Solving the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x^2}{\sin x}\mathrm{d} x$
I am having trouble integrating $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x^2}{\sin x}\mathrm{d} x$$I solved the integral of $x\csc x$ over the same bounds by using the tangent half-angle substitution and the series expansion of $\arctan x$, but if I do the same with this integral I get an $\arctan^2 x$ term that I do not know how to deal with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

According to Wolfram, the integral is equal to $2\pi C-7\zeta(3) /2$

@Gary Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for. How come I sometimes don't find the integral in am looking for on here? I looked for it but just couldn't find it.. do you have any tips on how to search better?

You can search using the TeX code of the formula at https://approach0.xyz/search/

@Gary Thank you!
